# How to map an object to a another object with some properties in a child object

Tags: automapper

Can any one suggest to me where i made the mistake?

```
public class DataModelProduct 
{
public int Id {get;set;}
public string Name {get;set;}
public string Price {get;set;};
public string Brand {get;set;}
public string Color {get;set;}
public string Dimentions {get;set;}
public string Type {get;set;}
public string Network {get;set;}
}

public class Product
{
public int Id {get;set;}
public string Name {get;set;}
public string Price {get;set;}
public Specification Spec {get;set;}
}

public class Specification
{
public string Brand {get;set;}
public string Color {get;set;}
public string Dimentions {get;set;}
public string Type {get;set;}
public string Network {get;set;}
}


AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap< DataModelProduct, Product>();
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap< DataModelProduct, Specification>();
```

You can assume `Product` class is Core Model and `DataModelProduct` is a Database Model

The `Product` properties are mapped but the `Specification` property is null.

Comment: Can you add your mapping code?

Comment: return this.DB.SingleOrDefault<DataModel.Product>("Where id = @0", productId).MapTo<Product>();

Comment: <DataModel.Product> and <Product> are definitely different references?

Comment: Never seen or used `MapTo` before (see my answer for classic syntax)

Comment: Yeah DataModel.Product looks like DB Table, and Product is my CoreModel both are different but ultimate goal is same...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give all your properties accessors for AutoMapper to function:

e.g.

```
public string Brand { get; set; }
public Specification Spec { get; set; }
```

And your mapping init code should be something like

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.CreateMap< DataModelProduct, Product>();
    cfg.CreateMap< DataModelProduct, Specification>();
});
```

And your runtime code like:

```
var product = Mapper.Map(dataModelProduct, new Product());
```

And the mapping to `Specification`:

```
var product = Mapper.Map(dataModelProduct, new Product());
product.Specification = new Specification();
Mapper.Map(dataModelProduct, product.Specification);
```

Comment: Thank you for the responce, But i gave accessors even it didn't work

Comment: You edited all properties on all source and destination classes including `DataModelProduct` ?

Comment: Yeah..I did thats why i posted this here, I've been working with automapper I have idea how to do but it's still not working.